# n() not showing in the summarise() output from tidyvesre in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I my code below, I was wondering why the result of `n = n()` is not shown in the final output?

```
library(tidyverse)
hsb <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')

hsb %>% dplyr::select(math, sector) %>% group_by(sector) %>% 
summarise(across(.fns = list(mean=mean, sd=sd), n = n()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the closing bracket of `across`.  We want the `n` to be a single column instead of repeating for each case, so for that, we can close the `across` and use `n = n()` separately i.e outside the `across`

```
library(dplyr)
hsb %>%
   dplyr::select(math, sector) %>%
   group_by(sector) %>% 
   summarise(across(.fns = list(mean=mean, sd=sd)), n = n(), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  sector math_mean math_sd     n
#   <int>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
#1      0      11.4    7.08  3642
#2      1      14.2    6.36  3543
```

---

Just to show that if we need multiple 'n' columns (not really needed).  Here, we `select` only two columns and one of them is the grouping column, so it would return only a single 'n'

```
hsb %>%
  dplyr::select(math, sector) %>%
  group_by(sector) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = list(mean = mean, sd = sd, 
         n = ~ n())), .groups = 'drop')=
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  sector math_mean math_sd math_n
#   <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <int>
#1      0      11.4    7.08   3642
#2      1      14.2    6.36   3543
```